# Oracle Stored Procedures using temp tables

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am fairly new to oracle and need to solve the following problem.

inside a stored proc I want to return 2 cursors like this.

```
PROCEDURE MyProcA()
as
begin

open refcursorA FOR
   select id, ..... FROM tableA where ..... long series of conditions

open refcursorB FOR
    select * FROM table b where b.id IN (select id FROM tableA where .....       long series of conditions)
```

This is how I have the stored proc at the moment but I don't like the repetition.  The where clause SQL in the parentheses in the 2nd cursor is exactly the same the first cursor.  How can I load it into a temp table or associative array or something to use in both cursors.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possibly with common table expression `WITH CTE as (SELECT * from tableName) SELECT * from CTE A INNER JOIN CTE B on A.ID+1 = B.ID)`  notice how the CTE is referenced twice. (A & B).. but without understanding context better  I'm not sure this is a valid answer.  Plus, why cursors?

Comment: How many rows would the first query return?  Are we talking about a small enough data volume that it would make sense to store in an in-memory collection?  Could you create a view for the first query that you reference when opening both cursors?

Comment: If the select from tableA doesn't contain parameters why not convert that into a view?

Comment: This is promising and I will investigate further.  So the CTE is separate from the refcursors?  Could you possibly show how the CTE would fit in in my example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need `REF Cursor`

**How to declare ?**

```
cursor cursor_name is ref cursor;
```

**How to use it ?**

```
open cursor_name for your select query
loop
fetch cursor_name into some_variable;
exit when cursor_name%notfound;
do_something;
end loop;
close cursor_name;
```

So, same cursor variable will point to different sql area dynamically.

**OR**

You can see [Cursor Expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions005.htm)

Comment: I have looked at a lot of variations of this.  It doesn't feel right.  I don't know when to exit.  I don't know what 'do something should be'. I don't know how to then use an array as a table in an IN (.....) condition.  I just want to have a common table/ collection/array of ids to use like this. SELECT * FROM TABLEA WHERE FK_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM MYTABLE/ARRAY/COLLECTION).  A view is not really appropriate as this id all happening inside a package SP and the long list of conditions is all input parameters.